# UserManager OIDC Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openid-connect, react-admin

I have questions regarding how the UserManager of the oidc client (described here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki) is working.

I'm using it with the 'code' response type. The questions I have are:

1/ The documentation states that the signinRedirect returns a promise to trigger a redirect of the current window to the authorization endpoint. But when exactly is the   "resolve" of this promise fired? Is it as soon as the redirect is being made? If so, the resolve is not the result of a successful authentication ...

2/ As a result, can this signinRedirect be used in another promise, such as the "login" of the authProvider of React-Admin?

3/ The response I obtain from the OIDC server has a code query parameter, which I then need to use to obtain the user info. Does the UserManager have methods to manager the subsequent calls required to the OIDC server to obtain the user info?

Thanks for any explanation you may provide.

Christian

Comment: The react-admin documentation contains an example of oidc implementation (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html#openid-connect-authentication-with-react-admin). does it help you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks François for your response. I saw the example you mention but I was struggling a bit to understand it into details. Hence I went on trying to do something a bit simpler ... which raised my questions above.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very nice library though the documentation is not great. Hopefully my experience and notes below are useful:

1. Usually these days you use an await that will result in the browser being redirected, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L106).
2. It is worth thinking about the coding model generally. React's main role is around view handling and not OAuth. Should you use plain Javascript classes for OAuth as in my [React Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa/)? Whatever you decide, the promise should be composable, but some options lead to simpler code than others.
3. To process the login response you need to call userManager.signInRedirectCallback() as part of your page load. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/28/basicspa-codingkeypoints/) explains this. You should not need to deal with any low level OAuth processing yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response ... quite a few things to look into but that should help me! Thanks.

Comment: @gary I'm also looking for the same kind of solution with oidc-client. But your code is written in Typescript right. I'm looking for code examples with jsx in react

Comment: @gary Do you know how to load the userManagerSettings values (client id, client secret, issuer url) from API calls instead of hard coded in redux-oidc library.

Comment: My code does this via a [config file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json) which is read into an object. You would use different files for DEV, STAGING, PROD. In some setups you might download the JSON from a configuration service. Note that it contains no secrets though.